# cannot return a [System.Data.DataTable] from a functioin in Powershell 5/6/7

Tags: .net, powershell, datatable

This code returns **$null**...

```
function T(){ 
    return [System.Data.DataTable]::new( "table1" ) 
    }
```

it should return a **Datatable** object,,,

but... **If i do it at Command-Line**

```
$x = [System.Data.DataTable]::new( "table1" )
Write-Host $x.TableName;
```

**IT WORKS FINE!!!**

---

- I also included ***Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data***
  but the result is the same
- I tested the same kind of code with, for example DataColumn
  and it works fine... *>>>???WEIRD!!!*

---

**?Any ideas...**

Comment: Change `return [System.Data.DataTable]::new( "table1" )` to `return Write-Output [System.Data.DataTable]::new( "table1" ) -NoEnumerate`

Comment: Hi Mathias... up a notch but no cigar... it returns a object names "List'1"... and if I try to cast it to [System.Data.Datable] it returns an exception... ?any idea why this happens in Powershell (why there is no problem at getting a datatable to a variable in command-line... but returning a datatable from a function gaves this weirdness???)

Comment: Read the answer I linked to - PowerShell enumerates the rows of the datatable at the first chance to be "helpful". `function T(){$table = [System.Data.DataTable]::new( "table1" );Write-Output $table -NoEnumerate}` should do

Comment: thanks again Mathis... I read the other answer and it helps,,, rely on a problem/solution I already encountered... the best way I found was to 'force' wrap the result in an array returning ( ,$object )... and when unraping I get the single object I want... but this is a mitigation... I think the Powershell team should work on this to prevent 'UNRAPING' when returning from a function... it can be kept in commandlets... there is too many collateral damage!!!

Comment: The automagical unravelling of enumerables (and datatables) is a feature - not a bug (however annoying it might sometimes be) :-)

Comment: as Powershell is evolving.. and becoming more used to make small programs... maybe it is time to "unfeature" some design errors and annoyances... this is a major one... it's not the first time it bytes me... this is a collateral effect that is very misleading... and prone to "problemas"... as an improvement in future editions I'd leave it as is for Commandlets... and remove the unrap from function return values...

Comment: I might not have been clear in my previous comment, but **the pipeline enumeration behavior that bites you is _at the core of PowerShell's value proposition_** - it literally wouldn't be PowerShell if it didn't do that. That being said, I'd strongly encourage you to [voice your concern/suggestions](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Issue-Enhancement%2C+Needs-Triage&template=Feature_Request.md&title=Feature+Request) if you want to get involved and contribute to the future of PowerShell :)

Comment: you wewe clear... I am only stating my oppinion...